# Prevent Typed DataSet updating PK column

Tags: c#, sql, primary-key, sql-update, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a typed dataset, and where I call `TableAdapter.Update(DataRow)`, the SQL executed includes an update of the primary key column of the database.

Unfortunately, when this code runs on a replicated database, the PK column has the `rowguid` property set, and I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Updating columns with the rowguidcol property is not allowed.
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataA...

How do I prevent the tableadapter from updating this column (the value is the same)?

Comment: On your typed dataset is the primary key column actually marked as the primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually edit the SQL created for the update command in the `DataSet` designer Just click on the adapter and find the `UpdateCommand`. Is there a reason that you're updating the primary key? If not (and you shouldn't be, if at all possible), then you should remove that from the command.

Comment: I totally *don't want* it to update the PK - that's the auto-generated SQL, not me.  You make a good point about editing it though.  Only trouble is that the edit will be lost if/when the class is regenerated through the designer <sigh>.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is actually marked as the primary key in the typed DataSet the auto generated updated statement should not be trying to update it.  I would look at the designer and double check that it is actually the primary key.

Comment: Yes = I've checked that and it looks fine.  I might try regenerating it from scratch and see if it makes any difference.